# How to start with ERC-4337?

Tags: erc-4337

I cannot find a guide about using ERC-4337 along with a Solidity contract.

- It is an interface like ERC-20, ERC-721 or ERC-1155?
- Could I use ERC-4337 just  importing the interface (from OpenZeppelin, for example), like IERC-20, IERC-721 or IERC-1155?
- [This will be the end version of the code](https://medium.com/infinitism/erc-4337-account-abstraction-without-ethereum-protocol-changes-d75c9d94dc4a)?
- [It is this the ERC-4337 "official" contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0576a174D229E3cFA37253523E645A78A0C91B57#writeContract)?
- How can I use it from my Dapp?

[According to Vitalik Buterin](https://medium.com/infinitism/erc-4337-account-abstraction-without-ethereum-protocol-changes-d75c9d94dc4a) there will be **no changes on the network**, in order to enable ERC-4337. So, I should be able to **connect my Dapp to the ERC-4337 Smart Contract** to manage new wallet addresses, based on smart contract accounts.

Comment: [ERC-4337 concerns mostly wallet developers and node developers](https://tradingstrategy.ai/blog/what-is-ethereum-erc-4337-account-abstraction). It does not concern Dapp developers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Backgound**

Very curious about ERC-4337, so after some research, I finally got it:

- It is everything about using **smart contract accounts over EOAs** (Externally Owned Accounts), implementing account abstraction (#ERC4337).
- The first draft about this topic was **proposed on 2021-09-29 by Vitalik Buterin** in "[ERC-4337: Account Abstraction Using Alt Mempool](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4337)"
- Now we have an "official" EntryPoint **Smart Contract deployed by [Ethereum Foundation](https://ethereum.org/en/foundation/)**, and [**audited** by Open Zeppelin](https://www.openzeppelin.com/).

These are the main components to ERC-4337:

1. **UserOperations** are pseudo-transaction objects that are used to
   execute transactions with contract accounts. These are created by
   your app.
2. **Bundlers** are actors that package UserOperations from a
   mempool and send them to the EntryPoint contract on the #blockchain
   network. Can receive UserOperations via a JSON RPC Client and submit
   them to the EntryPoint.
3. **EntryPoint** is a smart contract that handles the verification and execution logic for transactions.
4. **Contract Accounts** are smart contract accounts owned by a user.
5. [optional] **Paymasters** are smart contract accounts that can sponsor transactions for Contract Accounts, enabling gasless transactions in
   your apps.
6. [optional] **Aggregators** are smart contracts that can validate signatures for Contract Accounts.

The latest version of **EntryPoint contract so far (0.6.0) has been deployed** on multiple chains, in the same address `0x5ff137d4b0fdcd49dca30c7cf57e578a026d2789` for: [Ethereum](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5ff137d4b0fdcd49dca30c7cf57e578a026d2789), [Polygon](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x5ff137d4b0fdcd49dca30c7cf57e578a026d2789), [Optimistic](https://optimistic.etherscan.io/address/0x5ff137d4b0fdcd49dca30c7cf57e578a026d2789), [Avalanche (only testnet)](https://testnet.snowtrace.io/address/0x5ff137d4b0fdcd49dca30c7cf57e578a026d2789), [Gnosis](https://gnosisscan.io/address/0x5ff137d4b0fdcd49dca30c7cf57e578a026d2789) [and other supported networks](https://blockscan.com/address/0x5ff137d4b0fdcd49dca30c7cf57e578a026d2789):

- [Stackup](https://docs.stackup.sh/) was first to create a fully compliant bundler and a paymaster service.
- [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/account-abstraction) announced their first two products in the space: Bundler Services and Paymaster Services (wait list).

These ones have also built and deployed bundlers:

- [Biconomy](https://biconomy.gitbook.io/sdk/additional-content/account-abstraction#erc-4337-account-abstraction-via-entry-point-contract)
- [Blocknative](https://docs.blocknative.com/blocknative-auction/mev-bundle-rpc-endpoint)
- [Etherspot](https://docs.etherspot.dev/)
- [Candide wallet](https://docs.candidewallet.com/bundler/intro/)

According to the existing consensus, having multiple bundler clients is critical for the robustness of the protocol.

Taking the information above into account, **we can also answer the initial questions**:

> It is an interface like ERC-20, ERC-721 or ERC-1155?

No, it is a set of technical components, based on Smart Contracts. Currently there is an official EntryPoint Smart Contract developed and deployed by Ethereum Foundation, and audited by Open Zeppelin.

> Could I use ERC-4337 just importing the interface (from OpenZeppelin,
> for example), like IERC-20, IERC-721 or IERC-1155?

No, depending on the use case to achieve, you should use an available Bundler (or Paymaster) service provider, like [Stackup](https://docs.stackup.sh/), [Biconomy](https://biconomy.gitbook.io/sdk/additional-content/account-abstraction#erc-4337-account-abstraction-via-entry-point-contract), [Blocknative](https://docs.blocknative.com/blocknative-auction/mev-bundle-rpc-endpoint), [Etherspot](https://docs.etherspot.dev/) or [Candide wallet](https://docs.candidewallet.com/bundler/intro/)

> This will be the end version of the code?

The last audited version of the code [is on this Github repository branch](https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction/tree/6dea6d8752f64914dd95d932f673ba0f9ff8e144).

> It is this the ERC-4337 "official" contract?

The latest version (0.6.0) of the "official contract" is the **EntryPoint contract that has been developed and deployed in multiple networks, by the Ethereum Foundation, and audited by Open Zeppelin in the following address: `0x5ff137d4b0fdcd49dca30c7cf57e578a026d2789`

> How can I use it from my Dapp?

Depending on the use case, you have to choose a Bundler or Paymaster service provider.

Comment: Why are you linking the mev transaction bundle endpoint of blocknative as an EIP-4337 bundler?

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of ERC 4337 is that users from outside of the Ethereum can send transactions without having an account. You can send transaction-like objects to a separate mempool and someone else will make your transaction for you. This is helpful when users want to interact with blockchain without making an EOA from within an application.

> It is an interface like ERC-20, ERC-721 or ERC-1155?

No, it's a set of standards that helps protocols design their own account abstraction.

> How could I develop a Solidity contract compatible using ERC-4337 features?

There are several opcodes that are banned from being used if you want your contract to be deployable via ERC-4337

Overall, it's not a contract or interface, it's a set of standards that allows a design for account abstraction without consensus change.

Biconomy has a set of smart contracts that conform to ERC 4337, you can find the contracts [here](https://github.com/bcnmy/scw-contracts).

In my opinion, best resource to learn how ERC-4337 works is [the EIP itself](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4337).