# Does ERC-4337 require an update to the network?

Tags: gas, smart-contract-wallets, erc-4337, account-abstraction

My understanding was that we needed to update the network so that contracts can sign transactions and messages, and so that contracts can be called with just a secret key or other auth methods, rather than a full EOA.

But it seems like [Visa has already tested ERC-4337 on Goerli](https://www.theblock.co/post/231411/visa-taps-ethereums-goerli-testnet-to-experiment-with-account-abstraction?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social). I've seen several other services and platform claim to use ERC-4337 too. How is this possible? How can you make a contract do stuff without an EOA?

Edit: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/146979/103641 It seems I had an outdated understanding of AA. ERC-4337 has a very significant off-chain component apparently: "You can send transaction-like objects to a separate mempool and someone else will make your transaction for you."
This feels very censorable to me. I guess if you have multiple entrypoints, it's less censorable but still.